# Output an int array using hwnd window in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, hwnd

I recently created 2048 as console app using c++, now I was wondering if I could make it a bit more....prettier. So I'm checking out Windows programming with c++ over on msdn and just wanted to ask is it possible to output a single array element in subwindow and so on for each array element? For instance, 2048 uses 4x4 array, so if I created 16 subwindows (which is a lot) and then printed a single array element in each one along with redrawing them after every click....would that work? Or is there a soulution that's more simple?

Comment: Just drawing the blocks in one window seems a lot more simple than one window per block.

Comment: Well yh that's what I had in mind, maybe I didn't express in the best way....the only thing I don't know is which type should they be ?

Comment: It depends on what drawing technique you plan to use. Doing it in GDI is different than, say, SDL or GTK.

Comment: I'm not using SDL, I got it but I found it a bit complicated.                     I got as far as printing a string in main window with WM_PAINT that's why I'm asking.

Comment: If you're limiting yourself to GDI, I'd suggest reading some material on general GDI usage so you have some idea of how things fit together with it. For a block, `Rectangle` should suffice.

Comment: Will do m8, thanks for the help